# nodejs prioritise function execution

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, priority-queue, event-loop, ddp

I've edited a library ([ddp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp-client)) to make use of a heartbeat timer, which sends out a ping every X seconds. However, I'm also doing some work with the bluetooth hardware, which I believe is responsible for pings sometimes not returning in time (because the bluetooth seems to block the event loop temporarily). Is there a way to prioritise a certain function on the event loop, so it will always be executed before others? I don't think `setImmediate` would be suitable here, since I don't know exactly when the response message from the server would arrive.

The implementation of the timer is roughly as follows:

```
every X seconds
if(ping outstanding) {
  //Did not resolve in time
  closeConnection()
} else {
  ping outstanding = true
  sendPing()
}
```

This works perfectly fine if I run it without the bluetooth module. When I enable the bluetooth module, pings sometimes do not get resolved because the time taken to scan for bluetooth is sometimes longer than the interval of the timer, leading to a disconnect, while it's actually still connected.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prioritise a certain function on the event loop, so it will always be executed before others?

No.  node.js does not have a way for one piece of code to pre-empt another and always have priority.  Any code that "hogs" the CPU a bit or otherwise blocks the event loop a bit should either be fixed to not do that or it can be moved into it's own child process and you can communicate with it via any one of the many interprocess communication schemes.

Or, alternatively, if the ping timer is really, really important to run on time, then maybe it should be in its own child process where it can always just run as scheduled with no chance of something else interrupting it.

Implementing precise timers like this is one thing that node.js is just not good at.  Because it runs all your Javascript in a single thread, keeping a server instantly responsive or keeping timers running precisely on time requires that nobody ever blocks the event loop or hogs the CPU for longer than your timing threshold.  The usual work-around is to move things into their own child process where they get their own priority with the CPU.

Comment: @robvandijk - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stackoverflow.